# Find the sum to n terms of the series

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry

Find the sum to n terms of the series

$$\frac {\sin x}{\cos x+\cos2x} + \frac {\sin2x}{\cos x+\cos4x} + 
\frac {\sin3x}{\cos x + \cos6x} +\dotsb $$

How can I solve this?

Here is what I did for the first term:

$$\frac {\sin\bigl(\frac{3x}{2} - \frac x2\bigr)}
  {2\cos\bigl(\frac{x}{2}\bigr)\cos\bigl(\frac {3x}{2}\bigr)}$$

After opening $N^r$ by $\sin(A-B) = \sin A\cos B - \cos A\sin B$ we get

$$ \frac 12\left(\tan\frac {3x}{2} - \tan\frac {x}{2}\right)$$

But this doesn't work out for the remaining terms. Am I missing something here or is this method completely wrong? Any hints? Help please!

edit : Please give a hint. I want to do it on my own :)

Comment: What is the source of the problem? Had the $r$th term been $$\dfrac{\sin x}{\cos x+\cos2mx},$$  we could write $$\cos x+\cos2mx=2\cos\left(m+\dfrac12\right)x\cdot\cos\left(m-\dfrac12\right)x$$  and $$\sin x=\sin\left[\left(m+\dfrac12\right)x-\left(m-\dfrac12\right)x\right]=\cdots$$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee shouldn't the rth term be $ \frac {sin(mx)}{cosx + cos2mx} $ ?

Comment: That's why has the term been. What's the source?

Comment: @labbhattacharjee No I mean rth term for $N^r$ should be $sin(mx)$ instead of $sinx$ and what do you mean by source? Are you asking me where did I find this problem?

Comment: @Subham, Yes, the origin, I'm interested on

Comment: @labbhattacharjee Why? I found this in my study material for IITJEE. Im preparing for that. I haven't joined any coaching programs that is why I ask my doubts here.

Comment: @labbhattacharjee actually I solved it. Where do I post my solution? Do I edit the post or do I post an answer below?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I figured out the answer :

$ S = \frac {sinx}{cosx+cos2x} + \frac {sin2x}{cosx+cos4x}+ \frac {sin3x}{cosx+cos6x} + \quad ...$

Multiply both sides by $2sin\frac x2$

Take the first term :

$$\frac {2sin\frac x2sinx}{cosx+cos2x}$$

$$\frac {cos\frac{x}2-cos\frac {3x}2} {2cos\frac {3x}2cos\frac x2}$$

$$\frac 12(sec \frac {3x}2- sec \frac{x}2)$$

Now by same method we extend this to $n\ terms$ and add them

Finally we get,

$$2sin\frac x2S = \frac 12(sec (2n+1)\frac x2- sec \frac x2)$$

$$\therefore \quad S = \frac 14cosec\frac x2(sec(2n+1)\frac x2 - sec\frac x2)$$

This is the answer.

Comment: Why don't you mark this as accepted?